# sharing data between controller in Angularjs is not clear

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I created a common service to share the data between controller.

Below is the code snippet.

Here am getting undefined while using setter and getter. While accessing the object directly am getting the value. How to get the values using getter and setter.

what happens behind the scenes here.

```js
// JavaScript source code

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app',[])
    
})();


(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
      .module('app')
      .factory('appcontext', appContext);

    function appContext() {
        var service = {            
            getStartDate: getStartDate,         
          setStartTime : setStartTime,
            startTime : startTime
           
        };

        return service;

        //private variables       

        var startTime = '';
      

        function setStartTime(startTime) {
            startTime = startTime;
        }

        function getStartDate() {
            return startTime;
        }      
        
    }
})();


(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
           .controller("InsController", InsController)

    InsController.$inject = ['appcontext'];

    function InsController(appcontext) {

        appcontext.setStartTime(new Date());

        console.log(appcontext.getStartDate()); // undefined

        appcontext.startTime = new Date();

        console.log(appcontext.startTime); //prints the date correctly

    }          


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-App="app">
  
  <div ng-controller= "InsController">
    
    <div>{{ }}</div>
    
    </div>
  
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It is just the naming convention that is causing the conflict if I just replace your `setStartTime` method parameter name. Everything works well.

```js
// JavaScript source code

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app',[])
    
})();


(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
      .module('app')
      .factory('appcontext', appContext);

    function appContext() {
        var service = {            
          getStartDate: getStartDate,         
          setStartTime : setStartTime,
          startTime : startTime
        };

        return service;     

        var startTime = '';

        function setStartTime(newStartTime) {
            startTime = newStartTime;
        }

        function getStartDate() {
            return startTime;
        }      
        
    }
})();


(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
           .controller("InsController", InsController)

    InsController.$inject = ['appcontext'];

    function InsController(appcontext) {

        appcontext.setStartTime(new Date());

        console.log(appcontext.getStartDate()); 

        appcontext.startTime = new Date();

        console.log(appcontext.startTime); //prints the date correctly

    }          


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-App="app">
  
  <div ng-controller= "InsController">
    
    <div>{{ }}</div>
    
    </div>
  
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the functions you would like to expose. Since you have your getter and setter functions, don't return the variable itself, that wouldn't be much of a help. Create a variable `service` which stores every internal stuff you need and your functions should make use of that.

```js
// JavaScript source code

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app',[])
    
})();


(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
      .module('app')
      .factory('appcontext', appContext);

    function appContext() {
        var service = this;
        return {           
            getStartDate: getStartDate,         
            setStartTime : setStartTime          
        };

        //private variables       

        service.startTime = '';
      

        function setStartTime(startTime) {
            service.startTime = startTime;
        }

        function getStartDate() {
            return service.startTime;
        }      
        
    }
})();


(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
           .controller("InsController", InsController)

    InsController.$inject = ['appcontext'];

    function InsController(appcontext) {

        appcontext.setStartTime(new Date());

        console.log(appcontext.getStartDate()); // undefined

    }          


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-App="app">
  
  <div ng-controller= "InsController">
    
    <div>{{ }}</div>
    
    </div>
  
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks john. Both the solution works but i can mark as answer as only 1. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to eliminate the startTime variable and reference is as service.startTime. You've created a property for it on your service, but the rest of your code references the var rather than the property.

```
function setStartTime(startTime) {
    service.startTime = startTime;
}

function getStartDate() {
    return service.startTime;
}
```

Not sure if this is all your code, but it looks like some of the uses of StartDate should be StartTime as well.

Comment: Thanks Mike , but i can mark only one as answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My this blog post may help you :

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/05/04/how-to-share-data-between-controllers-in-the-angularjs.aspx